# Let $J \subset \mathbb{Z}$ be a set whose gcd is $d$. If $J$ is closed under addition, then $J$ contains almost all multiples of $d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $J$ be a set of nonnegative integers whose greatest common divisor is $d$. And suppose that $J$ is closed under addition, then J contains all but a finite number of integers in the set $ \{ 0,d,2d,3d,... \}$. I could hardly believe in this, I hope one of you could give me a proof on the statement mentioned above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? I'm having a hard time seeing the relation to stochastic processes.

Comment: This is just another way to state the finiteness of the Frobenius number:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem The same upper bound as in user940's answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134666

Answer (score 3):

Choose $j_1,\dots, j_r\in J$ with $\gcd(j_1,\dots, j_r)=d$.
The set $J$ contains all positive linear combinations
                      $p_1j_1+\cdots+p_rj_r$ where the $p_i$'s are non-negative integers.

**Claim:** $J$ contains all sufficiently large multiples of $d$.

**Proof.**   [By Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_for_several_integers) there are integers $c_j$ such that
                   $$   c_1j_1+\cdots+c_rj_r  =d.$$
Put $ s = j_1 + j_2 + \cdots + j_r$. Every integer $n$ has a representation
                       $$ n = xs + y $$
where $x$ and $y$ are integers and $0 \leq y < s$. Then
                      $$  nd = \sum_{k=1}^r ( dx + c_ky)j_k$$
and all the coefficients are positive if $dx > \max_k |c_k| s$.